# How to prompt the user to enter an integer and a character from the keyboard in C

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out the best way to get an integer and a character from a user

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    char b;
    printf("enter the first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter the second char: \n");
    scanf("%c", &b);

    printf("Number %d",a);
    printf("Char %c",b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is not shown correctly. Is there any problem with this?
[image]

Comment: new line character (the enter press) is the hidden ghost :)

Answer (score 3):

Your input and output statements are fine. Just replace `printf("Number %d",a);` with `printf("Number %d\n",a);` to better format the output. Also you should change your second scanf statement to `scanf(" %c", &b);`. This will deal with the newline character entered after the number is inputted.

Answer (score 2):

After you enter the number, you pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Since the `scanf` function works on the input *stream*, when you try to process the next `char` after reading the number, you are not reading the character you typed, but the `'\n'` character preceding that. (i.e. because the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you pressed added a `'\n'` character to your input stream, before you typed your `char`)

You should change your second call to `scanf` with the following.

```
scanf(" %c", &b);
```

Notice the added space character in the formatting string. That initial space in the formatting string helps skip any whitespace in between.

Additionally, you may want to add `\n` at the end of the formatting strings of both `printf` calls you make, to have a better output formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to take care of hidden character '\n' , by providing the space before the %c in scanf() function , so the "STDIN" buffer will get cleared and scanf will wait for new character in  "STDIN" buffer .

modify this statement in your program : scanf("%c",&b); to scanf(" %c",&b);